# Requirements for existence Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure corresponding to distribution function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I am going through Ash's book "Probability and Measure Theory". It says that:

We know that a distribution function of $\mathbb{R}$ determines a corresponding Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. This is true in n dimension if we change the definition of increasing.
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, and, for a $a \leq b$, let $F(a,b]$ denote

$\Delta_{b_1 a_1}\cdots\Delta_{b_n a_n} F(x_1\cdots x_n)=F_0-F_1+F_2-\cdots+(-1)^nF_n$ where $F_i$ is the sum of all $\binom{n}{i}$ terms of the form $F(c_1,\cdots,c_n)$ with $c_k=a_k$ for exactly $i$ integers and $c_k=b_k$ for remaining $n-i$ integers.

The function is said to be increasing iff $F(a,b]\ge0$ whenever $a\le b$; $F$ is right continuous iff it is right continuous in all variables together, in other words $x^1 \ge x^2 \ge\cdots\ge x^k \ge \cdots \to x$ we have $F(x^k)\to F(x)$

My Question: What does $a \le b$ mean here. Does it mean $a_j \le a_j$ in each dimension $j, 1 \le j\le n$
What does this definition of right continuous mean? Does it mean that if $x-x^k$ can be represented by any linear combination with positive coefficients in $n$ dimensions $F(x^k)\to F(x)$ as long as distance $d(x^k,x)\to0$, thus showing continuity in all directions(in increasing quadrant).